# passing paranter from asp.net to java script by JSON in html

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I want o pass some JSON object in HTML response and eval it in client. I used fallowing code in server:

```
 TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("script");
            tag.Attributes.Add("Id", id);
            tag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/html");
            tag.SetInnerText(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(content));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
```

and I try to eval it in client :

```
var p = eval("(" + pEl.html() + ")");
```

but it didn't work because of encoding so I have to decode it by this:

```
var p = eval("(" + pEl.html().replace(/&quot;/g,"'") + ")");
```

but it seem unpleasant , i try to use <%=%> in place of <%:%> in server side, but its remained same.
any idea to solve problem?
there is any better way to passing JSON along HTML response.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("script");
tag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(content);
tag.InnerHtml = "var p = " + json + ";";
return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
```

This declares a global javascript variable named `p` which contains the json object you could use everywhere in your scripts and you don't have to worry about replacing quotes or calling `eval`. You could name this variable using the `id` parameter for example if you don't want it to be called `p`.

Comment: No , its not work, its render " as &quot; yet and so its not accepted as JavaScript by IE.

Comment: Correct, I'm sorry, please see my update, use `InnerHtml` as `SetInnerText`.